# How to draw CALayer border around its mask?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, mask

So, I have a `CALayer`, which has a mask & I want to add border around this layer's mask. For example, I have set triangle mask to the layer and I want to have border around that layer.

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Actually, no. I needed this to show the selection of the layer. I ended up changing alpha of the layer.

Comment: @FahriAzimov please review, and consider my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Swift 4

[image]

```
class CustomView: UIView {
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    //setup path for mask and border
    let halfHeight = self.bounds.height * 0.5
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .bottomRight],
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: halfHeight,
                                                    height: halfHeight))

    //setup MASK
    self.layer.mask = nil;
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer

    //setup Border for Mask
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.path = maskPath.cgPath
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 25
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    borderLayer.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
}
```

Comment: @Cœur, I updated the code for swift 4, considering your comment.

Answer (score 6):

My approach in swift3.

```
// Usage:
self.btnGroup.roundCorner([.topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 4.0, borderColor: UIColor.red, borderWidth: 1.0)

// Apply round corner and border. An extension method of UIView.
public func roundCorner(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat, borderColor: UIColor, borderWidth: CGFloat) {
    let path = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    self.layer.mask = mask

    let borderPath = UIBezierPath.init(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
    let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.path = borderPath.cgPath
    borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
    borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    borderLayer.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider this example code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

    //Modify to your needs
    CGFloat maskInsetWidth = 5.0f;
    CGFloat maskInsetHeight = 5.0f;
    CGFloat maskCornerRadius = 5.0f;
    CGFloat borderWidth = 2.0f;
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    CGRect insetRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, maskInsetWidth, maskInsetHeight);
    insetRect.size.width = MAX(insetRect.size.width, 0);
    insetRect.size.height = MAX(insetRect.size.height, 0);

    CGPathRef path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:insetRect cornerRadius:maskCornerRadius].CGPath;

    if (borderWidth > 0.0f && borderColor != nil) {
        CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

        [borderLayer setPath:path];
        [borderLayer setLineWidth:borderWidth * 2.0f];
        [borderLayer setStrokeColor:borderColor.CGColor];
        [borderLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];

        borderLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        [self.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
    }
    [maskLayer setPath:path];
    [maskLayer setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    [self.layer setMask:maskLayer];
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks Werner. This is a good solution, if you are drawing the mask programmatically. What if the mask is being set from image? Any solution for that?

Comment: @FahriAzimov You may try to extract the path from the image: with [PocketSVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47969248/1033581) or [OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49366374/1033581)

Answer (score 4):

Some suggestions:

- Use an opaque shadow instead of a border (you will have a blurred effect).
- Create another layer, set its background color with the color you want for your border, mask it with a mask slightly bigger than the one you already have to simulate the border width, and put it centered behind your layer (may not work with every shape).
- Do a morphological operation on your mask image to calculate the border, for instance with the `vImageDilate` family of functions (more complicated, and may run into performance problems).
- If you know the shape and it can be described mathematically, draw it and stroke it explicitly with Core Graphics functions.
- Or, in the same case (shape known mathematically), use a `CAShapeLayer` to draw the border.

Answer (score 1):

In a general case you cannot easily set a border around a mask. That's like asking to put a border around the transparent pixels of an image. Perhaps it may be done using image filters. In some more specific case, if you are using plain CAShapeLayer then here is a sample of code that does that:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];

CALayer *hostLayer = [CALayer layer];
hostLayer.backgroundColor = [NSColor blackColor].CGColor;
hostLayer.speed  = 0.0;
hostLayer.timeOffset = 0.0;

CALayer *maskedLayer = [CALayer layer];
maskedLayer.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
maskedLayer.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
maskedLayer.bounds   = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);

CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.fillColor = [NSColor whiteColor].CGColor;
mask.position = CGPointMake(100, 100);
mask.bounds   = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 100, 100);
for (int i=0;  i<20;  i++) {
    double x = arc4random_uniform(2000) / 10.0;
    double y = arc4random_uniform(2000) / 10.0;
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, x, y);
}
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);

mask.path = path;

CGPathRelease(path);

maskedLayer.mask = mask;

CAShapeLayer *maskCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:mask]];
maskCopy.fillColor = NULL;
maskCopy.strokeColor = [NSColor yellowColor].CGColor;
maskCopy.lineWidth = 4;
maskCopy.position = maskedLayer.position;

// Alternately, don't set the position and add the copy as a sublayer
// maskedLayer.sublayers = @[maskCopy];

hostLayer.sublayers = @[maskedLayer,maskCopy];

_contentView.layer = hostLayer;
_contentView.wantsLayer = YES;

[CATransaction commit];
```

It basically creates an arbitrary path and sets it as the mask. It then takes a copy of this layer to stroke the path. You might need to tweak things to get the exact effect you are looking for.

Comment: Instead of `archivedDataWithRootObject`+`unarchiveObjectWithData` to create an exact copy, it may be faster to create a new layer (`[CAShapeLayer new]`) and simply set its `bounds` and `path` manually again.

Answer (score 1):

If you subclass `CALayer`, you could instantiate it with the mask you want, and also override `layoutSubLayers` to include the border you want. This will work for all masks and should be the new accepted answer.

Could do this a couple ways. Below Ill do it by using the `path` of the given mask, and assigning that to class property to be used for constructing the new border in `layoutSubLayers`. There is potential that this method could be called multiple times, so I also set a boolean to track this. (Could also assign the border as a class property, and remove/re-add each time. For now I use bool check.

**Swift 3:**

```
class CustomLayer: CALayer {

    private var path: CGPath?
    private var borderSet: Bool = false

    init(maskLayer: CAShapeLayer) {
        super.init()
        self.path = maskLayer.path
        self.frame = maskLayer.frame
        self.bounds = maskLayer.bounds
        self.mask = maskLayer
    }

    override func layoutSublayers() {

        if(!borderSet) {
            self.borderSet = true
            let newBorder = CAShapeLayer()

            newBorder.lineWidth = 12
            newBorder.path = self.path
            newBorder.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            newBorder.fillColor = nil

            self.addSublayer(newBorder)
        }

    }

    required override init(layer: Any) {
        super.init(layer: layer)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```